# Why do internal inconsistencies occur in Main.storyboard and how do I get around it?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I open a project from XCode 8 on Sierra macOS, which was working on yesterday with no problems.
Now I see:

> The document "Main.storyboard" had 2 internal inconsistencies that
>   were found and repaired. This may be due to an SCM operation such as
>   merging.  Please save the document to fix the inconsistencies.

[image: storyboard errors]

I cannot click either of those buttons.  They don't respond.
I cannot do anything except close the project. 
What should I do now to fix this?

Does anyone know reasons that this occurs?

Comment: I've filed a bug report: 29162925

Comment: Thanks, Frankie. This is a dupe of radar://28339876, and a known regression in Xcode 8.1, we have a fix ready for 8.2 (it's not in 8.2 beta 1, unfortunately).

Comment: @QuinnTaylor given how debilitating this issue is, you may want to release the fix in Xcode 8.1.1. I have to force quit Xcode every time I want to edit my storyboard because I can't get rid of this dialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot believe I found the answer...well, got to a solution on this terrible thing that seems to be caused by XCode's interaction with the built-in Source Control.

I had to close XCode a number of times to finally get to this. I was hacking the main.storyboard file using a text editor.  I tried all kinds of things.

Finally, I thought about the error message more.

What was "**SCM**" in that original message?  I guessed it was Source Control Module because it mentioned merging.

I then noticed that the capital "M" next to my main.storyboard file on the left where the project files are listed.  It looks like:

[image: project files modified]

I guessed that was showing me that Source Control was saying it was "M"odified so I right-clicked on the main.storyboard file and told it to discard changes.

It looks like the following:

[image: roll back changes]

After that, I was able to open the storyboard again. 
The odd thing is that at one point I was even able to run the project while it was in the corrupted state.
Took a lot of finagling to get it done.

The XCode Devs have to fix this.  It's terrible.

**EDIT 2**
Ugh! What a waste of time.  Every time I go to view the storyboard again, then the SCM merges something in and finally i do see something that has to do with the error. it looks like:
 [image: large stack view]

oh, sure, it's probably something I've done with the InterfaceBuilder and it's my fault and all, but the terrible horrible stupid XCode has let me do it.

**Edit 3**
Okay, I noticed that it believes the label is all stretched out.  But, it's the source control merge thing that is automatically doing this.  I wonder if my entire project is going to be toast? 
[image: label has huge height]

**Edit 4**

I was able to get further through this problem with a few more details so I wanted to document them to help others.

**Part of the Root Cause**

The issue was that for some unknown reason a specific label when placed inside a stackview would go bonkers and attempt to be 9,000,0000,000 units in height.

**One Way To Fix**

Take a quick look at the 2nd image in this post.  It shows where I right-click on the main.storyboard file.  I actually saw the label go crazy again with the huge height when Interface Builder attempted to render the storyboard and then I was able to

1. choose *Open With External Editor*
2. Search for the offending size (I searched for 9,000,000)
3. alter the size in the file and save and then Interface builder re-renders properly.

**Conflicting Constraints**

I also found a number of conflicting constraints which were questionable and I got all of those settled.  After that, I did still see the label go crazy if I copied it into the StackView but at least I could alter it via editing it in the text editor.
Good luck.

Comment: This offending size may not be big as 9,000,000. Heights that bigger than 10,000 causes same problem.

Regex for finding heights bigger than 10,000: height="\d{5,}"

Comment: @tolpp thanks for adding the regex.  That's a great idea for finding the source of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue (5 internal inconsistencies), and found a solution similar to @daylight, but thought I could add more color.

First - useful to highlight how debilitating this was - I could not close the dialog, and thus could not change anything in the storyboard to fix it - horrible bug.

The problem:

- on Xcode 8, Xcode was silently changing the storyboard massively (can track the changes via git).   Some of these changes added ridiculous heights to labels in stackviews (as per @daylight). Presumably xCode was trying + failing to resolve layout conflicts automatically.   These changes were causing / associated with the dialog in this question, which causes a crash.
- Once xcode adds these changes, the only way to access the file is by opening as source.
- The very first time Xcode 8 opens the storyboard + right after it asks for you to choose a viewing device,  I was able to access the the storyboard graphically, which gave me an opportunity to inspect it.
- I was not able to fix problems by simply discarding / fixing changes,  as Xcode would then make them again.

Solution:

- By carefully tracking + reverting changes made via git, and looking for crazy high height numbers, I was able to trace the problems to stackviews in one view.   I took all my content out of those stackviews (in that brief opportunity when I could access the storyboard graphically) + deleted them.   Problem solved.   Now I just need to reformat that view, which in my case is not too much work.

Comment: @Phil-Ken-Sebben It seems that the bug appeared in the same way as it did in mine -- related to a UIStackView going crazy. Thanks for chiming in on this.